# How to use SFINAE to enable implicitness of explicitness of the conversion operator?

Tags: c++11, implicit-conversion, sfinae, explicit, conversion-operator

Consider the following code:

```
// Preamble
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// Wrapper
template <class From>
struct wrapper
{
    // Implicit conversion
    template <class To, class = typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_convertible<From, To>::value
    >::type>
    constexpr operator To() const noexcept;

    // Explicit conversion
    template <class To, class = typename std::enable_if<
        !std::is_convertible<From, To>::value
        && std::is_constructible<To, From>::value
    >::type>
    explicit constexpr operator To() const noexcept;
};

// Main
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    wrapper<int> x;
    double y = x;
    return 0;
}
```

Ideally this code would make the conversion operator implicit when `From` is implicitly convertible to `To`, and make the conversion operator explicit when `To` is explicitly constructible from `From`.

However, the code currently does not compile because from the compiler standpoint, both conversion operators have the same signature.

**Question:** Would there be any way to trick the compiler to produce the expected behavior?

---

**Answer:** full code based on [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53049032/882932)'s answer:

```
// Preamble
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// Wrapper
template <class From>
struct wrapper
{
    // Implicit conversion
    template <class To, typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_convertible<From, To>::value,
    int>::type = 0>
    constexpr operator To() const noexcept(noexcept(From{})) {
        return From{};
    }

    // Explicit conversion
    template <class To, typename std::enable_if<
        !std::is_convertible<From, To>::value
        && std::is_constructible<To, From>::value,
    int>::type = 0>
    explicit constexpr operator To() const noexcept(noexcept(From{})) {
        return From{};
    }
};

// Main
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    wrapper<int> x;
    double y = x;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just replace your `class = typename std::enable_if<...>::type` pattern with `typename std::enable_if<..., int>::type = 0`. The SFINAE parameter is then a non-type template parameter of a different type, and the functions overload corerctly.